# How to target my portable class library in a Nuget-Package?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to create a Nuget Package for another project, which has the following targets set in the project properties:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- ASP.NET Core 1.0
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone Silverlight 8
- Xamarin.Android
- Xamarin.iOS
- Xamarin.iOS (Classic)

The project I create the package from is targeting exactly the same.

In the Nuget Package Explorer I created a `lib` folder and in that `lib`-Folder I added another folder with `Add Portable Library` and the following settings:

- .NET Framework v4.5 and higher
- Windows Phone 8

**The directory name after creation is:**

portable-net45+wp8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=net45+wp8)

I published the Nuget Package to my private repository and tried to import it into my project I described above, but it is giving me an error:

> Could not install package 'my.package 0.0.1-alpha1'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

Can anyone tell me, how to set my package up correctly, so my package can be imported? What is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NuGet package has the portable profile:

```
portable-net45+wp8
```

Profile 78 has the portable profile:

```
portable-net45+win8+wp8
```

So the problem is that the profile you are using does not indicate that it supports Windows 8 (win8) so NuGet believes it is not compatible with Profile 78.

If your portable class library assembly targets Profile 78 then it should be OK for you to rename that directory to include win8 so it becomes `portable-net45+win8+wp8`

Comment: thank you, seems to work so far. I have another question. I added a few dependencies to my package (SignalR.Client) and put it into <group targetFramework=".NETPortable0.0-net45+win8+wp8">. Why does nuget say "unsupported" in the description?, when I try to add it a project. The main dll is referenced after installing, but the dependencies are not getting installed.

Comment: I would guess that NuGet does not recognise the target framework. Where are you seeing unsupported and what version of NuGet and/or Visual Studio are you using? Looking at the SignalR.Client NuGet package, which has a similar dependency seems OK with NuGet 3 in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Hm, I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I have installed an up to date Nuget package Manager Extension installed. I doubt it, but could it be a server sided issue? I am using a custom PHP Server as the nuget package server.

Comment: Possibly. SignalR.Client has a similar dependency if that is OK when you are searching nuget.org then it might be your custom server.

Comment: Let me check that out later today. I will try to create a repo locally and will get back to you, when I can.

Comment: Okay, I tried it out and it really is the server :/